# Copy a file from an archive to a different directory python

Tags: python, copy

is there any simple way to copy a file inside an archive to a different path? Obviously, the simple method of using shutfile doesn't work:

```
 from shutil import copyfile
 copyfile("path/archive/file.ext", "newpath/newfile.ext")
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

LE: Imo, the error is misleading, because it probably shows up because I have a zip archive in the path ( if I extract the file from the archive and change the path, it works without problems, my problem is that it doesn't go through the archive)

Comment: There are 2 possible problem: 1)your file is not in the directory or 2)your path is wrong.

Comment: Make sure your source file `path/archive/file.ext` exists. Where directory `path` should exist in the same directory as your script (or in your current directory).

Comment: what is OS ? if its windows user `//` instead of `/`

Comment: You can prepend your path `r`. For example, `r"C:\Users\user\foo.ext":

Comment: My problem is that I have a zip archive I think, not because it really can't find the path.

Comment: Can you share your file with a link if you can?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way i found:

```
import os
import zipfile
import shutil

with zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(basePath + arcName)) as z:
    with z.open(fileInArc) as zf, open(os.path.join(newPath, newName), 'wb') as f:
        shutil.copyfileobj(zf, f)
```

It simply unpack a single file in directory you need with name you choose